# PySide2 QPushButton.setText() crashes my application after halting video feed

Tags: python, pyside2

I am creating a widget that shows a live camera feed from a machine vision camera on a custom widget derived from QLabel.

However, when I stop the live view of the feed, my program crashes silently.
When I use the debugger, the last executing line is `self.ui.btn_prev_st.setText('Start')` on the button with which I stopped the feed. If I step over it, I step into the `update_image()` of the CameraControl, but the application closes while the debugger is still halted.
After that, `app.exec_()` seems to return and the application closes.
For image acquisition I use pymba. I call the `self.cam.disarm()` function right before the `setText()`, but it executes normally if I step through. (It calls `gc.collect()` at the end, but that shouldn't do anything?)
So either I borked something in Qt or the pymba disarm function is the cause.

Does anybody have an idea? I provided a minimal working example.
Thanks in advance!

main.py code:

```py
import sys
import os
import atexit

from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PySide2.QtCore import QFile, Signal
from PySide2.QtUiTools import QUiLoader
from ui_main import Ui_main
from camera_control import CameraControl

class main(QMainWindow):
    start_acquisition_signal = Signal()
    stop_acquisition_signal = Signal()
    def __init__(self):
        super(main, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_main()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        atexit.register(self.cleanup)
        self.ui.btn_prev_st.clicked.connect(self.prev_start_pushed)
        self.ui.btn_set_roi.clicked.connect(self.ui.camera_prev.apply_roi)
        self.ui.btn_reset_roi.clicked.connect(self.ui.camera_prev.reset_roi)
        self.start_acquisition_signal.connect(self.ui.camera_prev.start_preview)
        self.stop_acquisition_signal.connect(self.ui.camera_prev.stop_preview)

    def __del__(self):
        del self.ui.camera_prev

    def cleanup(self):
        del self

    def load_ui(self):
        loader = QUiLoader()
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "form.ui")
        ui_file = QFile(path)
        ui_file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)
        loader.load(ui_file, self)
        ui_file.close()

    def prev_start_pushed(self, event):
        if self.ui.btn_prev_st.text() != 'Stop':
            self.start_acquisition_signal.emit()
            self.ui.btn_prev_st.setText('Stop')
        else:
            self.stop_acquisition_signal.emit()
            self.ui.btn_prev_st.setText('Start')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    widget = main()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

camera_control.py:

```py
from typing import Optional
import cv2
import numpy as np
from pymba import Vimba, Frame

from PySide2 import QtGui
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QLabel
from PySide2.QtCore import Signal, Slot, Qt, QPoint, QRect, QSize
from PySide2.QtGui import QPixmap

class CameraControl(QLabel):
    change_pixmap_signal = Signal(np.ndarray)
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CameraControl, self).__init__(parent)
        self._first_show = True # whether form is shown for the first time
        self.is_running = False
        self.change_pixmap_signal.connect(self.update_image)
        self.vimba = Vimba()
        self.vimba.startup()
        self.cam = self.vimba.camera(0)
        try:
            self.cam.close()
        except:
            pass
        self.cam.open()
        self.setup_camera()
        self.update()

    def __del__(self):
        try:
            self.cam.disarm()
            self.cam.close()
        except:
            pass
        del self.vimba

    @Slot()
    def stop_preview(self):
        self.is_running = False
        #self.cam.stop_frame_acquisition()
        self.cam.disarm()

    @Slot()
    def start_preview(self):
        self.cam.arm('Continuous', self.frame_handler)
        self.cam.start_frame_acquisition()
        self.is_running = True

    def frame_handler(self, frame: Frame, delay: Optional[int] = 1) -> None:
        img = frame.buffer_data_numpy()
        self.change_pixmap_signal.emit(img)

    @Slot(np.ndarray)
    def update_image(self, cv_img):
        """ Updates the image_label with a new opencv image"""
        qt_img = self.convert_cv_qt(cv_img)
        self.setPixmap(qt_img)
```

ui_main.py:

```py
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *

from camera_control import CameraControl


class Ui_main(object):
    def setupUi(self, main):
        if not main.objectName():
            main.setObjectName(u"main")
        main.resize(1192, 752)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(main)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.box_preview = QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.box_preview.setObjectName(u"box_preview")
        self.box_preview.setGeometry(QRect(10, 10, 601, 391))
        self.btn_prev_st = QPushButton(self.box_preview)
        self.btn_prev_st.setObjectName(u"btn_prev_st")
        self.btn_prev_st.setGeometry(QRect(20, 20, 75, 23))
        self.camera_prev = CameraControl(self.box_preview)
        self.camera_prev.setObjectName(u"camera_prev")
        self.camera_prev.setGeometry(QRect(110, 20, 480, 360))
        self.camera_prev.setMinimumSize(QSize(0, 0))
        self.camera_prev.setBaseSize(QSize(640, 480))
        self.camera_prev.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.camera_prev.setFrameShape(QFrame.Panel)
        self.camera_prev.setScaledContents(False)
        self.camera_prev.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        main.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QMenuBar(main)
        self.menubar.setObjectName(u"menubar")
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 1192, 21))
        main.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QStatusBar(main)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(u"statusbar")
        main.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(main)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(main)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, main):
        main.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("main", u"main", None))
        self.box_preview.setTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("main", u"Preview", None))
        self.btn_prev_st.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("main", u"Start", None))
    # retranslateUi
```

Comment: It is definitely caused by the camera object, but I don't know why.
When I don't emit the change_pixmap_signal, the application does not crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use the official VimbyPython library instead. This fixed the issue.